# Using CMake to resolve #include dependencies in an exotic language

Tags: include, cmake, build-dependencies

I'm trying to use CMake as my build tool driver *(I make it clear at once that I'm quite new to CMake since this my first on-my-own CMake project)*. My project is mainly C with some files in an exotic language I'll call here Z. These Z files must be processed by their Z compiler to produce .h and .c files.

I managed to tweak CMake handle Z compiling  and dependencies between plain C files and generated Z -> .h header with

```
add_custom_command( ...*details omitted*... )
set_source_file_properties(*generated-.h* PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE)
```

and CMake C-`#include` scanner does properly the rest of the job.

Now, Z files use something equivalent to C `#include` construct and I'd like to make profit of automatic recompilation when one of the Z-included files changes.

If a.Z includes inc.Z, I tried:

```
set_source_file_properties(a.Z PROPERTIES OBJECT_DEPENDS inc.Z)
```

but that doesn't trigger automatic recompilation of a.Z.
 [CMake manual](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_sf/OBJECT_DEPENDS.html) says this property was introduced for this purpose and is no longer necessary for C/C++. However it is ineffective in my Z case.

If I modify my custom command as follows:

```
add_custom_command( ... DEPENDS inc.Z ...)
```

I get the desired result, but not all Z files depend on inc.Z (another one might depend on inc2.Z).

I then tried to generate dynamically the `DEPENDS` list with

```
get_source_file_property(dependencies ${filename} OBJECT_DEPENDS)
if(dependencies STREQUAL "NOTFOUND")
    unset(dependencies)
else()
    string(REPLACE ";" " " dependencies "${dependencies}")
endif()
add_custom_command(... DEPENDS $filename "$dependencies" ...)
```

and make errors out with

```
Make[2]: *** no rules to build target `-- content of dependencies variable --'
```

*Note: error is the same with or without double quotes around variable substitution*

I guess CMake interpreted my list of dependencies as a single (non-existent) filename and make was unable to handle that. Anyway, the files mentionned in the `dependencies` variable are not meant to be compiled, only to be included somewhere. They must make their way to make only as dependencies.

**Which direction should I go to achieve the desired result?**

Recall this is my first *on-my-own* CMake project and I certainly made newbie errors.

*FWIW, my platform is Linux with CMake 2.8.9 (not bleeding edge but I'm only exploring) and KDevelop 4.x*

Thanks for your help.